# How to support unicode for UserName?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, aspnetboilerplate, asp.net-core-identity

I add a register feature that needs unicode support for `UserName` (Chinese for now). When I input Chinese `UserName`, there is an error window that pops up:

> User name xxxxx is invalid, can only contain letters or digits.

I search source code and do not find any validator or filter for that. I check the SQL Server schema, the `UserName` type is `nvarchar(32)`, which is unicode enabled.

Could anyone please tell me how to add unicode support for that field? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of ASP.NET (Core) Identity.

You can do the following to disable validation.

## ASP.NET Core Identity

**IdentityRegistrar.cs**:

```
return services.AddAbpIdentity<Tenant, User, Role>(options =>
{
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null;
})
```

## ASP.NET Identity (MVC 5)

**UserManager.cs**:

```
(UserValidator as Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.UserValidator<User, long>)
    .AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false;
```